# Selenium select element that contains string python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

i am trying to select and option value from a select item.

But i need to select the one that contains on innerhtml or value attribute some string.

This is my element that i want to click

```
<option value="01050160181160053049|DEPOSITO|CC|ACTIVOS|105">01050160181160053049 - hhh</option>
```

I dont know how to select it using xpath or something like that and then click it. Can you help me here?

here is my code, it works when clicking on the select input, but then i need to select the element (exist many different options) that contains a specific string on value or innerhtml.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#formContainer > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td.contentA2 > select').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),'01050160181160053049')]').click()
```

It cant find the element using xpath.

Solution:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="formContainer"]/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/select/option[contains(@value, "' + cuenta + '")]').click()
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code. Is there an URL to share? And what specifically are you after? The option above for example: is it static? Can it change?

Comment: @QHarr thank you. i edit the post, please check i explain it better

Comment: @QHarr that does not work, i can select the specific item using css selector '#formContainer > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td.contentA2 > select > option:nth-child(19)' on 'option:nth-child(19)' is where i need to identify the one that got my value

Comment: I know. That is why I had already deleted my comment. I didn’t read the last bit properly. You should be able to use contains to identify a specific string in xpath though.

Comment: @QHarr dont worry thank you so much for your help. Can i change this part 'option:nth-child(19)' to give there an specific value to select?

Comment: i can use '//*[@id="formContainer"]/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/select/option[19]' and it selects my item. But i want to get the one that includes on value my string '01050160181160053049' no matters if the value got another text like '01050160181160053049|DEPOSITO|CC|ACTIVOS|105' i want to select it just using a part of the value

Comment: @qharr i make it work using 'browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="formContainer"]/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/select/option[contains(@value, "' + cuenta + '")]').click()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selects all the 'option' elements that have an attribute named 'value',
maybe you can put them in a list and loop over them until one or more match your conditions

`//option[@value]`

Source:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: I can use xpath '//*[@id="formContainer"]/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/select/option[19]' and that will select my item but i want to change 'option[19]' so it can select the one that contains my specific value